# fatal error: Index out of range in swift while taking options from uipicker

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have 3 text field like to select gender, country, state. And I am using `UIPicker` to get the input values from `UIPicker`. But now when I press gender `UITextField` to open UIPicker`enter code here`, the UIPicker`enter code here` is showing with no data. But the same `UIPicker` I am using for the country, state. that time it's showing the data with `UIPicker` for both countries, state text field. Can anyone please help me out. How to solve this problem.

Error :

> fatal error: Index out of range

If I press in uipicker option view only its crashing.

My code :

I am getting a crash in this class file :

```
import Foundation

import SwiftCountryPicker

class DataPicker: NSObject, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

    var dataPicker: UIPickerView!
    var inputText:UITextField!
    var parent:UIViewController!
    var pickerData: [String]!
    var feetStr = String()
    var inchStr = String()

    private var _selectedValue: String!

    var selectedvalue: String {
        return _selectedValue ?? String()
    }

    func showPicker(parent:UIViewController,inputText:UITextField, data: [String], selectedValueIndex: Int){

        self.inputText = inputText
        self.parent = parent
        pickerData = data

        if dataPicker == nil {
            dataPicker = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,parent.view.frame.size.width, 216))
            dataPicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            dataPicker.dataSource = self
            dataPicker.delegate = self
            dataPicker.selectRow(selectedValueIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
            _selectedValue = pickerData.count > 0 ? pickerData[selectedValueIndex] : ""
        }
        inputText.inputView = dataPicker

        // ToolBar
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        toolBar.barStyle = .Default
        toolBar.translucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(hex: "B12420")
        toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        // Adding Button ToolBar
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(DataPicker.doneClick))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(DataPicker.cancelClick))
        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
        inputText.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    }

    func doneClick() {
        inputText.text = _selectedValue
        inputText.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    func cancelClick() {
        inputText.resignFirstResponder()
    }




    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return pickerData.count
    }
    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return pickerData[row]
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        _selectedValue = pickerData[row]
    }

}
```

**In this line :**

> func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int,
>   inComponent component: Int) {
>
> ```
>         _selectedValue = pickerData[row]
>     }
> ```

And my text field delegate for press the texfield:

```
extension UserInfoViewController:UITextFieldDelegate{

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        selectedText = textField

else if  textField == genderss {
            ctDataPicker = DataPicker()
            let indexPos = genders.indexOf(genderss.text!) ?? 0
            ctDataPicker.showPicker(self, inputText: textField, data: genders,selectedValueIndex: indexPos)
        }

}
}
```

Comment: first check `let indexPos = genders.indexOf(genderss.text!) ?? 0` indexPos value and  'pickerData' count is same

Comment: once check pickerData it has any data or not?

Comment: what value contains genders array?

Comment: Technically that does not happen since you populated the picker with the same Array. You might want to check if the array mutated between populating the picker and selecting a row.

Comment: @AndeySatyanarayana Satyanarayana      The number is 0 (indexpos)
The ndata is 0  (pickerData.count)

Comment: @PiyushRathi The number is 0 (indexpos)
The ndata is 0  (pickerData.count)

Comment: @mack that's reason of app crash, have you initialise pickerData? use `self.pickerData` everywhere

Comment: the above post is full code of my `DataPicker`. Where should i need to initialize that `self.pickerData`

Comment: @mack where you declare `genders`? you are passing this value to showPicker

Comment: @PiyushRathi  i am new to handle ios. i declare it in some utlity.swift file. Can u please send me ur email id, i will share my proejct to u. Can you please help me out ??

Answer (score 1):

`UIPickerViewDataSource` method `didSelectRow` is changed in Swift 4:

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return pickerData[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    TextField.text = myPickerData[row]
}
```

Try changing the line crashing _selectedValue to a textfield example

TextField.text = myPickerData[row]

Check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipickerview) on `UIPickerView`.